# Debug application over internet using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following problem:

My phones USB port is broken and I have no way of running app on the phone other than sending it over bluetooth and install it every time I make changes to the code. So every time I make changes, I gotta spend min+ to see them in action. I don't want to use emulator.

Is there a way I can make eclipse run my app on the phone over the internet when I build/run the app the same way it does over USB? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: is the usb port completely broken, or just for charging? my S3 port broke, but the data still worked, it just wouldn't charge. look into "ADB over WIFI" as njzk2 said, it works great, and no USB cable needed ( hopefully you have it setup already... )

Comment: Thanks! my usb works in an opposite way. It charges, but no data transmission :( Turns out my phone has to be rooted, and as far as I understood I can't do ADB over WIFI unless my phone is rooted. :(